# zen-coding: ability to ascend the DOM tree using ^

Tags: javascript, regex, coffeescript, emmet

I forked the excellent zen-coding project, with an idea to implement DOM ascension using a ^ - so you can do:

`html>head>title^body>h1` *rather than* `html>(head>title)+body>h1`

Initially I implemented with rather shoddy regex methods. I have now implemented using @Jordan's excellent answer. My [fork is here](https://github.com/itaccess/zen-coding)

### What I still want to know

Are there any scenarios where my function returns the wrong value?

Comment: That doesn't look like something you can do with just a regular expression.  I'd figure out exactly what your grammar is and then write a real parser for it.

Comment: I think it already has a very good tokenizing parser - just that I don't know how it works. I was hoping someone could assist.

Comment: Some things are too complex to sanely process in regex, perhaps you should have some code to do this instead. For a massive project I worked on I used a mixture of straight string replacement, regex, and logic statements in code to process html documents. Tokenizing parsers cannot alone perform much logic and as a result are sometimes unable to handle weird cases.

Comment: @tchrist will be able to write a regex for this I bet...

Comment: This belongs on [Codereview.SE].

Comment: @zzzzBov Huh, I did not know that site existed. Thank you for adding to my Stack Exchange knowledge! :)

Comment: If the question was on Code Review, then @Jordan would not have seen it, and could not have given his excellent and useful answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Disclaimer:** I have never used zen-coding and this is only my second time hearing about it, so I have no idea what the likely gotchas are. That said, this seems to be a working solution, or at least very close to one.

I am using [Zen Coding for textarea v0.7.1](http://code.google.com/p/zen-coding/downloads/detail?name=Zen.Coding-textarea.v0.7.1.zip) for this. If you are using a different version of the codebase you will need to adapt these instructions accordingly.

A couple of commenters have suggested that this is not a job for regular expressions, and I agree. Fortunately, zen-coding has its own parser implementation, and it's really easy to build on! There are two places where you need to add code to make this work:

1. Add the <kbd>^</kbd> character to the `special_chars` variable in the `isAllowedChar` function (starts circa line 1694):

   ```
   function isAllowedChar(ch) {
       ...
       special_chars = '#.>+*:$-_!@[]()|^'; // Added ascension operator "^"
   ```
2. Handle the new operator in the `switch` statement of the `parse` function (starts circa line 1541):

   ```
   parse: function(abbr) {
       ...
       while (i < il) {
           ch = abbr.charAt(i);
           prev_ch = i ? abbr.charAt(i - 1) : '';
           switch (ch) {
               ...
               // YOUR CODE BELOW
               case '^': // Ascension operator
                   if (!text_lvl && !attr_lvl) {
                       dumpToken();
                       context = context.parent.parent.addChild();
                   } else {
                       token += ch;
                   }
                   break;
   ```

   Here's a line-by-line breakdown of what the new code does:

   ```
   case '^':                         // Current character is ascension operator.
       if (!text_lvl && !attr_lvl) { // Don't apply in text/attributes.
           dumpToken();              // Operator signifies end of current token.

                                     // Shift context up two levels.
           context = context.parent.parent.addChild();

       } else {
           token += ch;              // Add char to token in text/attribute.
       }
       break;
   ```

The implementation above works as expected for e.g.:

```css
html>head>title^body
html:5>div#first>div.inner^div#second>div.inner
html:5>div>(div>div>div^div)^div*2
html:5>div>div>div^^div
```

You will doubtless want to try some more advanced, real-world test cases. [Here's my modified source](http://pastebin.com/7SkDLbd4) if you want a kick-start; replace your `zen_textarea.min.js` with this for some quick-and-dirty testing.

Note that this merely ascends the DOM by two levels and does not treat the preceding elements as a group, so e.g. `div>div^*3` will not work like `(div>div)*3`. If this is something you want then look at the logic for the closing parenthesis character, which uses a lookahead to check for multiplication. (Personally, I suggest not doing this, since even for an abbreviated syntax it is horribly unreadable.)

Comment: I tested it all out, it works great. It is also an education for me on how the parser works (I still have much to learn). You really made the problem seem simple. Thanks. I also agree that `div>div^*3` is confusing syntax and I see no benefit really.

Comment: Thanks @Billy! Glad to help. The `expandAbbreviation` method seems like a good place to start if you really want to grok what's going on; follow the calls from there and you'll be taken on a tour of most of the important stuff. :)

Answer (score -1):

You should look for Perl's [Text::Balanced](http://perldoc.perl.org/Text/Balanced.html) alternative in the language that you're using.